# pymongo==3.0.3: ImportError: No module named connection

Tags: python, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I just upgraded to `pymongo==3.0.3` via `pip install --upgrade pymongo`, and I'm flooded with `ImportError`:

```py
In [2]: pymongo.version
Out[2]: '3.0.3'

In [3]: from pymongo import Connection
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-dd44bc3249d3> in <module>()
----> 1 from pymongo import Connection

ImportError: cannot import name Connection

In [4]: from pymongo import connection
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-71c9e4ec1bcd> in <module>()
----> 1 from pymongo import connection

ImportError: cannot import name connection

In [5]: import pymongo.connection.Connection
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-282b89157c85> in <module>()
----> 1 import pymongo.connection.Connection

ImportError: No module named connection.Connection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Pymongo 3.0 changelog](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/changelog.html#mongoclient-changes) -

> **MongoClient changes**
>
> MongoClient is now the one and only client class for a standalone server, mongos, or replica set. It includes the functionality that had been split into MongoReplicaSetClient: it can connect to a replica set, discover all its members, and monitor the set for stepdowns, elections, and reconfigs. MongoClient now also supports the full ReadPreference API.
>
> The obsolete classes MasterSlaveConnection, Connection, and ReplicaSetConnection are removed.

As you can see Connection class has been removed from pymonge 3.0 , try using MongoClient instead. Information about mongoclient can be found [here](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html#pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can support both versions in your code by doing something like this.

```
try:
    from pymongo.connection import Connection
except ImportError as e:
    from pymongo import MongoClient as Connection
```

Comment: is it a question or answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Since Connection class is deprecated from pymongo(3.0.0). Install a older version of pymongo(2.9) to make it temporarily work. It can be done with pip using:

```
pip install  pymongo==2.9
```